# Generating new angular application creates an old angular version project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed the latest version of node.js and so when I check version with `node --version` it says `v14.15.3` Correctly and when I run in cmd `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` it also correctly says `11.0.5`.

When I run `ng new Demo` it creates an angular 6 project .

I don't know why this happens.

I want to create angular 11 project

Thanks in  advance

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Are you trying this on Linux or Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing latest version of LTS node using:

```
https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.3/node-v14.15.3-x64.msi
```

[image]

You have to execute those 2 command lines in an **empty directory**:

create an **empty new directory**: test

```
c:\test\npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

And

```
c:\test\ng new Demo
```

And cd to Demo directory, you will find this package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

And you see that I've just created it and it's an angular 11 application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked you Angular version after the installation? run `ng --version` in the terminal window. ( Out of Angular project directory ).

You must get something like that:

[Screenshot of the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhVM7.png)

otherwise try to run installation command with `sudo` e.g. `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.